# Error 404 not found raises 500 when Debug set to False

Tags: django, debugging, http-status-code-404

I recently tried to implement a custom view for my 404 and 500 errors on my website. It works well when debug is set to True, i.e. both the custom views work well when called. But as soon as set my Debug to False only the error 500 will be raised

I tried already to call them by creating a url, both of the handler404 and handler500 custom view works well.

This is the view where it should raise an error 404 when badly called:

```py
def arret(request, id):
    """ Page that show an textuel """
    view = 'search/arret.html'
    arret = get_object_or_404(Arret, id=id)
    arret.compute_bgeref_id()
    query = request.GET.get('q', '')

    form_class =  DecisionForm()
    title = arret.highlight_words(query,input_text=arret.title)

    text = arret.highlight_words(query)
    arret_judges = arret.arret_judges.all()
    decision = arret.decision
    return render(request, view, {'title': title,'text': text, 'date':arret.date, 'tag_string': arret.tag_string, 'tags': arret.get_n_tags(), 'articles': arret.get_n_law_articles(n=15),
                                'bgeref_id': arret.bgeref_ids.all(),"form": form_class, 'id':id, 'query' : query, 'decision': decision,'arret_judges':arret_judges, 'ATF':arret.source=='ATF'
                                })
```

Here you can find my 404 custom view:

```py
def handler404(request, template_name="colorlib-error-404-19/index.html"):
    response = render_to_response("colorlib-error-404-19/index.html")
    response.status_code = 404
    return response
```

it raises an error 500 when trying to find a non existing Arret.
this is what is written in the terminal

```sh
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
June 22, 2019 - 08:55:31
Django version 2.0, using settings 'nora.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[22/Jun/2019 08:55:32] "GET /arret/100/?q=loi HTTP/1.1" 500 1435
```

Edit: add settings file

Here is my settings_file:

```py
import os
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth
import elasticsearch

user = os.getenv('USER')
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY =  ##########################

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True
if user == 'user':
    DEBUG = False
else:
    DEBUG = True

# ALLOWED_HOSTS

if user == 'user': # Checks if the settings is on the website
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = [ '.neuralen.ch', '.mstamenk.webfactional.com' ]
else :
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'haystack',
    'search',
    'authUser',
    'debug_toolbar',
    'haystack_panel',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'nora.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates"),],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                "django.template.context_processors.i18n",
            ],
        },
    },
]

#TEMPLATE_DIRS = ( failed attempt
#    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
#)

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'nora.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#databases

if user == 'user': # Check if settings.py is on website server
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': 'nora_db',
            'USER': 'neuralen',
            'PASSWORD': #################,
            'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
            'PORT': '5432',
        },
        'nora_db_2': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': 'nora_db_2',
            'USER': 'neuralen',
            'PASSWORD': '################',
            'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
            'PORT': '5432',
        }

    }
else:                   # Otherwise, it's in local
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),


        },
        'nora_db_2': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'second_db.sqlite3'),
        },

    }

#DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['search.routers.SearchRouter']


# AWS 
AACCESS_KEY = ##########################
SECRET_KEY = ##########################
REGION = 'us-east-1'
AWSHOST = 'https://search-nora-y6ko4vsxcd4255tcs4gznzbaou.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com'


awsauth = AWS4Auth(AACCESS_KEY,SECRET_KEY,REGION,'es')

# Haystack connection to elasticsearch.
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35090762/django-haystack-using-amazon-elasticsearch-hosting-with-iam-credentials?rq=1

HAYSTACK_CUSTOM_HIGHLIGHTER ="nora.utils.nora_Highlighter"

HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack_es.backends.Elasticsearch5SearchEngine',
        #'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/',
        'URL': AWSHOST,
        'INDEX_NAME': 'nora',
        'INCLUDE_SPELLING' : True,
        'KWARGS': {
            'port': 443,
            'http_auth': awsauth,
            'use_ssl': True,
            'verify_certs': True,
            'connection_class': elasticsearch.RequestsHttpConnection,
        }
    },
}

if user == 'user':
    HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS['default']['INDEX_NAME'] = 'nora-server'
else:
    HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS['default']['INDEX_NAME'] = 'nora'


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

#LANGUAGE_CODE = 'fr'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

gettext = lambda x: x

LANGUAGES = (
   ('en', _('English')),
   ('fr', _('French')),
   ('de', _('German')),
)

LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
)


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/

if user == 'user': # Check if on website
    STATIC_URL = 'https://neuralen.ch/django_nora_static/'
else:                  # Otherwise running in local
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/"),
)
if user == 'user':
    STATIC_ROOT = '/home/user/webapps/django_nora_static/'
else:
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_root/")

# Authentification

LOGIN_URL = 'accounts/login'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

#SMTP Email Serivce
#https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/06/13/how-to-send-email.html
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.sendgrid.net'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'testsite_app'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '################'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'TestSite Team <noreply@example.com>'
#EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'  # During development only

INTERNAL_IPS = [ '127.0.0.1']
DEBUG_TOOLBAR_PANELS = [
    'debug_toolbar.panels.versions.VersionsPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.timer.TimerPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.settings.SettingsPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.headers.HeadersPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.request.RequestPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.sql.SQLPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.staticfiles.StaticFilesPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.templates.TemplatesPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.cache.CachePanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.signals.SignalsPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.logging.LoggingPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.redirects.RedirectsPanel',
    'haystack_panel.panel.HaystackDebugPanel',
     ]
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be your settings file does not have `ALLOWED_HOSTS`

Django 1.5 introduced the [allowed hosts setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts) that is required for security reasons.

```
# Hosts/domain names that are valid for this site; required if DEBUG is False
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
```

Add your host here like `['www.example.com']` or `['*']` for a quick test, **but don't use `['*']` for production**.

Alternatively, it could be you're trying to access some static file without running [collectstatic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django-admin-collectstatic). In most cases, this should be a 404 after loading the response in the view, but if you're accessing them in the code, it could be a 500.

Comment: I do have ``` ALLOWED_HOST = [*] ``` for debugging I also think it’s due to static files but it seems not  to be an issue for the rest of my pages ( and static files are called normally for my error 500 page)

Comment: you might have to post your settings (without any keys) and your urls, but first please post the full code for `def arret`

Comment: @MartinBarry please add the **full** code `def arret`

Comment: @MartinBarry I'm really sorry but I'm completely baffled. I don't know what could be wrong. Ideally you should get a 404. Perhaps there is something wrong in your 404 template. Check your logs or admin crash emails

Comment: thanks !  I can still not find the error. I'll come back if I ever do